# read() end line not being found causing code to output weird symbol

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[10];
    int ret;
    while(1) {
        ret = read(0, buf, sizeof buf);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Basically, this is what happens:

```
$ gcc -Wall above.c
$ ./a.out
h
h
@

a
a
&
^C
$
```

How do I make it so that this special character is not printed? I'm unsure how to fix this. I tried making `buf[10] = '\0'` but I still get the same error.

Comment: In C, arrays ranged from `0` to `N-1`, so by doing `buf[10] = '\0'`, you are out of range for an array of 10 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors, why don't use the return value of read?

Simply you can use it in a `"%.*s"` format specifier, like in

```
         printf("%.*s\n", ret, buf);
```

but....

- you have to check that `ret < 0`  for errors.
- you have to check that `ret == 0` for End of file condition.
- `read(2)` **never** terminates the sequence of characters read with a `\0` char, so you cannot use any `str*` function on it (I used the trick of printing only the first `ret` chars  because the `ret` variable tells me there are not more, so I don't get behind the last character read)  but this approach will eat all the characters read after an actual `\0` in the input file (or in the buffer), up to the `ret`-esim char.  That is because the `%*s` format stops before the specified `ret` value if it finds the string terminator null char.

It is better to use `write(2)` or `fwrite(2)` with `read(2)`, as in:

```
         write(1, buffer, ret);
```

As `read(2)`, `write(2)` doesn't treat `\0` as a string terminator, and case you have some `\0` chars in the buffer, it will print them, as if they were normal characters.  This is important if you do want verbatim output from input (as in `cat(1)` command)

Comment: For completeness, it might be worth mentioning hat `read()` returns `ssize_t` not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`read()` does not zero terminate anything. It is a function that is used to read **any** bytes from a file descriptor, including zero bytes. As such, zero terminating the result would be kind of pointless. Instead, `read()` returns the amount of bytes that were successfully read. You must interpret that return value if you want to do correct reading.

Answer (score 0):

you should set buf[ret] to '\0' not buf[10].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[10];
    int ret;
    while(1) {
        ret = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf));
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

well, as commented there are some mistakes in my answer. I just want to point out the single point, so I haven't consider too much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[10];
    int ret;
    while(1) {
        ret = read(0, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1); // keep last byte for termination charactor
        if (ret == -1) {
            printf("error:%s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        } else if (ret == 0) {
            // end of file. such as ctrl + D
            break;
        } else {
            // ret certainly less than sizeof(buf)
            buf[ret] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", buf);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623290/read-end-line-not-being-found-causing-code-to-output-weird-symbol#comment86254596_49623404).

Comment: *you should set buf[ret] to '\0' not buf[10].* No, because `ret` can also be 10.

Answer (score 0):

`buf[10] = ...` is undefined behavior. The buffer goes from 0..9, so the naive approach should be  `buf[9] = 0;`.

This still doesn't work because it is not linked to how much you actually read. You do know this because of the `ret` variable - so add `buf[ret] = 0;` before trying to output `buf`.

edit: as pointed out in the comments, if the full amount of chars has been read (in this case 10) then `buf[ret]` is the same as `buf[10]` and so it is still undefined behavior. Easiest solution is to ensure the buffer is bigger than the max size you are trying to read.

Comment: `buf[ret] = 0;` this might still cause undefined behaviour if `sizeof buf` `chars`s had been read.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the 'buf' with null. As 'buf' is declares local array and you didn't initialize it with null, 'read' call is reading up to sizeof(buf) which is 10 bytes. If you giving input string less than sizeof(buf) size, then it will read the remaining junk characters from the 'buf'. So initialize the 'buf' with null.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[10] = {'\0'};
    int ret;
    while(1) {
        ret = read(0, buf, sizeof buf);
        printf("\n%s\n", buf);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: The idea is to terminate the 'buf' with null at the end of the string. read() call doesn't append the EOF or null at the end of the string.

Comment: *The idea is to terminate the 'buf' with null at the end of the string. read() call doesn't append the EOF or null at the end of the string.* And neither does setting the entire buffer to `\0` when `sizeof(buf)` bytes are read.